# My DIY tube amplifier distorts more than I planned

Tags: amplifier, distortion, tube

I have built a JTM145 clone. The original amplifier is clean and distorts when the volume is turned up, but my own copy of that amplifier distorts at low volume at the second 12AX7 tube from pin 7 to 6; I checked that with my oscilloscope. I don't understand why it distorts so much at low volume at that stage.

After the power transformer I added a 0,4 kΩ (3 x 1,2 kΩ parallel) voltage drop resistor, because I only could get a 200 V output transformer and no 180 V. I'm not sure if it is connected to the problem.

[image]

Comment: Are the markups on the schematic yours? Are you really running the tubes at half the recommended heater voltage? That would seriously limit the emissivity of the cathode and I wouldn't be surprised if that causes the excessive distortion. If you have only 6.3V available, you should be running the heaters in parallel rather than in series. I doubt whether the plate voltage is an issue.

Comment: Yes the markups are from me. No I dont use the heater at half voltage. I use them in parallel

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine Start with the 1st stage and disconnect everything else. (Disconnect **LOUD**, so that only the signal from the plate output of the 1st stage is present at **LOUD** and the rest is disconnected.) What do you measure there with your signal applied? (And what is the signal input level, by the way?) I'm also curious what you are getting for the average grid voltage referenced to the cathode. And what's the plate voltage supply rail at the 1st stage?

Comment: As @periblepsis states, check all grid voltages -- is the tube properly biased for class A operation? Single-ended tubes need to be in A region, push-pull output should be biased for A-B (i.e., small DC out from each to reduce crossover distortion of B alone).

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine Let's walk through what to expect on the 1st stage. (Yes, I know you are complaining about the 2nd stage. But first things first.) From the schematic I read \$180\:\text{V}\$ for the secondary. This is RMS. So after the bridge rectifier I'd expect about \$250\:\text{V}\$. There's likely to be some drop across the two series resistors getting to the 1st stage, so I'm calling it \$B^+=240\:\text{V}\$. I'm using [this 12AX7 datasheet](https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/1/12AX7A.pdf) and drawing out a simple load line (that ignores the cathode resistor.)

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine I've also included the cathode resistor's line so that the intersection can be found in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qn3U.png). That's an estimate, of course. But it does provide a ballpark for the DC bias point. From there, and just eyeballing the grid curves, I'd estimate a grid bias of about \$-1.3\:\text{V}\$ and therefore a plate current of about \$870\:\mu\text{A}\$. Check the plate, grid, and cathode voltages and see if they reflect those quantities, within reason. The plate resistor should have about \$90\:\text{V}\$ across it, for example.

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine The next page can be used to estimate the amplification factor, \$\mu\$. There, it suggests \$\mu=100\$. (Triodes are relatively flat in terms of the amplification factor.), I also think I get \$g_m\approx 1200\:\mu\mho\$ and \$r_p\approx 74\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Given the AC-grounded cathode, I'd suggest \$A_v= -\frac{\mu}{1+\frac{r_p}{R_p}}\$, so I find \$A_v\approx -57\$. I'd hope to see something akin to that at the unloaded **LOUD** connection, if you'd disconnect it from the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Strangly I could fix the problem simply by switching v1 and v2 tube. One problem remainig is that if i play a very loud chord it sounds very unpleasent and adding a high pitched popping noise